# React native : What is the way to take data from 1 function and pass it to function number 2?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, parameter-passing, fetch-api

What is the way to take data from `getUserConnectRequestData` function and pass it to `getUserConnectResponseData` function  ?
as you can see so i try to use `then` and  `responseData` to for save the data of the `getUserConnectRequestData` function and than i try pass it into the `getUserConnectResponseData` function but itd not works .

```
getUserConnectRequestData().then(() => {
          responseData();
        });
```

and this is `getUserConnectResponseData` function that i want to pass the data from `getUserConnectRequestData`

```
export const getUserConnectResponseData = (responseData) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // console.log('THIS IS MY RESPONSE ==============>>>>>>>>>>>', responseData);
    try {
      fetch(
        'https://hghghgghghg3223223',
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            Req_Type: responseData.Req_Type,
            Language_Code: responseData.Language_Code,
            User_ID: responseData.User_ID,
            Session_ID: responseData.Session_ID,
            Session_Key: responseData.Session_Key,
            Client_Type: responseData.Client_Type,
            Req_Data: {
              Bridge_ID: responseData.Bridge_ID,
            },
          }),
        }
      )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((jsonResponse) => {
          resolve(jsonResponse);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Also note this: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Answer (score 0):

You need to accept the parameter and use it, and call the right function:

```
getUserConnectRequestData().then((responseData) => {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^
    getUserConnectResponseData(responseData);
// −^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−^^^^^^^^^^^^
});
```

But since `getUserConnectResponseData` takes just that one parameter you know that the `then` callback will only be called with that one single argument:

```
getUserConnectRequestData().then(getUserConnectResponseData);
```

You also need to handle errors, so:

```
getUserConnectRequestData()
.then(getUserConnectResponseData)
.catch(error => {
    // Handle/report error
});
```

---

There are a couple of other things to point out, though:

1. `getUserConnectRequestData` is falling prey to a promise anti-pattern: You don't need `new Promise` when you *already* have a promise (from `fetch`) to use.
2. You need to check for HTTP success before calling `.json()` on the response. Sadly, `fetch` only rejects on *network* errors, not HTTP errors.

Here's an updated version of `getUserConnectRequestData`:

```
export const getUserConnectResponseData = (responseData) => {
    return fetch('https://hghghgghghg3223223', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            Req_Type: responseData.Req_Type,
            Language_Code: responseData.Language_Code,
            User_ID: responseData.User_ID,
            Session_ID: responseData.Session_ID,
            Session_Key: responseData.Session_Key,
            Client_Type: responseData.Client_Type,
            Req_Data: {
                Bridge_ID: responseData.Bridge_ID,
            },
        }),
    })
    .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
        }
        return response.json();
    });
};
```

Because of that need for the check, I never use `fetch` directly, I have wrappers to do the check so I don't have to code it Every Single Time.

```
// General purpose
function fetchGeneral(...args) {
    return fetch(...args)
    .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
        }
        return response;
    });
}

// JSON
function fetchJSON(...args) {
    return fetch(...args)
    .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
        }
        return response.json();
    });
}
```

Those reject on both network and HTTP errors.

Comment: FWIW, I go into promises (including useful patterns and warnings of anti-patterns) in Chapter 8 of my new book. Check my profile for details if you're interested.